# Multiple Comparison AND and NOT in Python

Tags: python

I am newb in Python. I want to make combination of AND and NOT operator, but it didn't work. I expect the result would be True if someone is under or equal to 30 y.o, male, and an Indonesian or Malaysian. I will appreciate your help. You can give another example of AND and NOT combination without If-Else statement. Thanks.

```
def job_vacancy_requirements(age, gender, nationality):
    gender = ['male', 'female']
    nationality = ['indonesian', 'australian', 'malaysian']
    return (age <= 30) and (gender == 'male') not (nationality == 'australian')
print(job_vacancy_requirements(25, 'male', 'indonesian'))
print(job_vacancy_requirements(30, 'female', 'malaysian'))
print(job_vacancy_requirements(27, 'male', 'australian'))
```

Comment: You are overriding the value of gender with the list assignment. Same for nationality

Answer (score 0):

You are simply missing one `and` statement there. And no need to use    parenthesis in Python unless you need to group your conditions.

```
return age <= 30 and gender == "male" and not nationality == "australian"
```

A bit politically incorrect method, by the way....

Answer (score 0):

This works fine. Remove list assignment, that is gender and nationality within the function .

```
def job_vacancy_requirements(age, gender, nationality):
    return (age <= 30) and (gender == 'male') and (nationality != 'australian')
print(job_vacancy_requirements(25, 'male', 'indonesian'))
print(job_vacancy_requirements(30, 'female', 'malaysian'))
print(job_vacancy_requirements(27, 'male', 'australian'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the assignment in the compare function will get it work.

The reason that your code didn't work is the assignment inside your compare function changes the value of gender and nationality.

> ```
> def job_vacancy_requirements(age, gender, nationality):
>     gender = ['male', 'female']
>     nationality = ['indonesian', 'australian', 'malaysian']
>     return (age <= 30) and (gender == 'male') not (nationality == 'australian')
> ```

is equivalent with

> ```
> def job_vacancy_requirements(age, gender, nationality):
>     return (age <= 30) and (['male', 'female'] == 'male') not (['indonesian', 'australian', 'malaysian'] == 'australian')
> ```

so, the return value of job_vacancy_requirements is always false, because

```
['male', 'female'] == 'male'
```

is always false.